# Коды. HexDump. Сохранение

Tags: cmd

Нашёл online-converter "HexDump Online: show contents of a binary file in hex" - https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm

Скачал их программу "command line version of hexdump".

Как при использовании hexdump в командной строке сохранить код в txt ?

Answer (score 1):

В документации к версии для командной строки сказано: "It just takes a list of files and dumps the contents in hex on `stdout`."

Это значит, что в конце командной строки надо добавить `> имяфайла` и вывод пойдет в этот файл.

Comment: Добавил " >> путь к файлу" - получилось...

Comment: @user318092 `>>` означает "дополнить файл, если он уже есть".  `>` означает "перезаписать файл".

Comment: Если файла нет оба варианта работают...

Comment: @user318092 Если файла нет, оба варианта работают одинаково. Если файл есть - по-разному. Зачем вам сразу понадобился именно `>>` - не ясно.

Comment: В интернете информация по командной строке неполная...